# How to install Doctrine Extensions in a Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I guess that this is really trivial and stupid question, but I don't know how to install Doctrine Extensions - https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions in my Symfony2 project. I need them because of the MONTH, YEAR functions. Where should I put their  folder? And should I put the whole `DoctrineExtensions` folder? And where to write this:

```
<?php

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('DoctrineExtensions', "/path/to/extensions");
$classLoader->register();
```

In a separate file? Where to put it and how to call it?

And then is this all I need to use them:

```
public function findOneByYearMonthDay($year, $month, $day)
{
    $emConfig = $this->getEntityManager()->getConfiguration();
    $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year');
    $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('MONTH', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month');
    $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DAY', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day');
```

Thank you very much in advance and sorry once again for the question, but I couldn't find a tutorial (which makes me feel even more guilty, because I guess it's too trivial when there isn't even a tutorial)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can install it via composer. Just add it to your composer.json and then `php composer.phar update beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`

```
"beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "*",
```

Then you can register functions to your ORM

```
doctrine:
    orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
      entity_managers:
        default:
          auto_mapping: true
          dql:
            datetime_functions:
              MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
              YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

Comment: Wats the function for "DAY" ??

Comment: [DAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) is a synonym for DAYOFMONTH()

Comment: @forgottenbas how to add all functionality?

Comment: @Subdigger what do you mean?

Comment: @forgottenbas DoctrineExtensions contain many other functions. do i must write them all to config or there any way to add DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\* ?

Comment: @Subdigger simplest way is to add all this functionos to config. Also possible to define it somethere in compiler pass.

Comment: You can list basic functions from http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use DoctrineExtensions in the context of Symfony using the DoctrineBundle.

First install the package DoctrineExtensions:

```
composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions
```

Then add to your doctrine configuration (`doctrine.yaml` file) the DQL functions you want to include in your application:

```
doctrine:
    # Register types this way in the dbal config part
    dbal:
        types:
            carbondatetime: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonDateTimeType
    # Register DQL functions in the ORM part
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                FIND_IN_SET: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\FindInSet
            numeric_functions:
                SIN: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Sin
            datetime_functions:
                DATE: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Date
```

This is an example, feel free to adjust to your needs (you can remove sections).

Answer (score 1):

There also is a nice fork by wiredmedia of @beberlei which includes even more datetime_functions like **DATE()** itself:

[This is an unsanctioned fork of https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions since he seems to have gone off grid and is not merging pull requests.](https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions)

Unfortunately Version 0.1 just includes the fork and not all the functions.
We are waiting for a stable release:

[Please create taged stable version for set in my composer #2](https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions/issues/2)

But you can add them manually unitl a stable version is out.