# How to install DoctrineExtensions in Symfony 2.5 and latest

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-extensions

I need use mysql functions in qb such as DATE(), NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME() etc. I reading this topic [How to install Doctrine Extensions in a Symfony2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894966/how-to-install-doctrine-extensions-in-a-symfony2-project). I did it:

```
composer require "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions":"dev-master"
```

all became normal:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Installing beberlei/doctrineextensions (dev-master 5e4ec9c)
Cloning 5e4ec9c3ec3434151e1c73144b4ab87ae30aefbc
etc...
```

Еhen I did it:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
      entity_managers:
        default:
          auto_mapping: true
          dql:
            datetime_functions:
              MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
              YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

BUT! Symfony return this exception for me:

```
FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "/home/domain/www/domain.com/app/config/config.yml" from "/home/domain/www/domain.com/app/config/config_dev.yml". (A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation at line 106 (near " dql:").)
```

Sorry for my english, but in russia internet segment no normal specialists for Symfony2 framework. I hope for your help, my friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error:

```
A YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation at line 106 (near " dql:")
```

You have tabs in this file:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
      entity_managers:
        default:
          auto_mapping: true
          dql:
            datetime_functions:
              MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
              YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

Instead tabs create spaces.