# Doctrine Extensions REGEXP not working in Symfony2

Tags: php, regex, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine 2.1 and need to use a REGEXP in MySQL.

REGEXP is not currently supported in the default installation of Doctrine so I am using beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

I cannot get Doctrine to recognize my REGEXP, I have followed the example on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894966/how-to-install-doctrine-extensions-in-a-symfony2-project).

I'm using Doctrine 2.1 and Symfony 2.7.1

Here's the code, any ideas?

Config

```
# config.yml
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        keep_slave: true
        slaves:   %database_slaves%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: cache
        dql:
            string_functions:
                regexp: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Regexp
```

Repository

```
// GroupRepository
            $dql = "SELECT g FROM {$this->_entityName} g WHERE g.name REGEXP '^[:alpha:]'";
            return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)->getResult();
```

Error on page load

```
// Error
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 64: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'REGEXP'" at /symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 52
```

UPDATE:

I've updated the query to match the expected format

```
    $dql = "SELECT g FROM {$this->_entityName} g WHERE REGEXP(g.name, '^[:alpha:]')";
```

Now I have started getting a new error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string.
```

Comment: I think you need to do it like `WHERE REGEXP(g.name, '^[:alpha:]')`. This  will then get translated by the extension to `(g.name REGEXP '^[:alpha:]')`.

Comment: @Qoop I changed my query to match your suggestion but now I'm getting `[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string.`

Comment: @Qoop If I add an `= 1` at the end of the query, it runs but now the SQL isn't what I need :-(  `SELECT g FROM {$this->_entityName} g WHERE REGEXP(g.name, '^[:alpha:]') = 0 `

Comment: I found that my character class was incorrect it is supposed to be `'^[^[:alpha:]]'`, which complicated finding the solution

Comment: So what was the final answer? Out of interest.

Comment: @Qoop the issue was that I had to add an `= 1` to the end of the REGEXP expression so that Doctrine would recognize it.  I posted my answer below, but I can't accept my own answer until tomorrow

Comment: Yeah, sorry. My bad. Didn't use my eyes properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution through the [github page](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/pull/120) for the project

Doctrine requires that all where clauses require a comparison operator even though a clause like REGEXP doesn't require it.

```
$dql = "SELECT g FROM {$this->_entityName} g WHERE g.status = 1 AND REGEXP(g.name, '^[^[:alpha:]]') = 1";
```

Also my regex character class was incorrect in my original question.

Comment: the quotes are important!
->andWhere("REGEXP(t.something, '^[0-9]{12}$') = 1") - works
->andWhere('REGEXP(t.something, "^[0-9]{12}$") = 1') - doesn't work